# Can I cache multiple tables in one cache, or do I need to maintain separate caches for each?

Tags: java, performance, caching, guava

I'm setting up a cache with Guava, but I need to cache multiple tables.  In a previous project, I was able to cache multiple tables due to the JSON object being a nested object - the JSON of one table were nested in the JSON of another.  In this case, the code is set up so that nesting does not occur, so I can't just cache the one JSON object that contains all others.  As such, I'd like to know if I can set up Guava Cache to hold the contents of multiple tables in one cache, or if I have to set up multiple caches.  I haven't found anything about one shared cache yet, and I'm concerned about the potential performance hit multiple caches might cause.

Answer (score 0):

> As such, I'd like to know if I can set up Guava Cache to hold the contents of multiple tables in one cache, or if I have to set up multiple caches.

With any cache you can do both. For a shared cache you need to compound key, e.g.:

```
class TableIdTuple {
  String tableName;
  int id;
  TableIdTuple(String tableName, int id) { ... }
  boolean equals(...) { ... }
  int hashCode() { ... }
}
```

Then you can access the cache with:

```
cache.get(new TableIdTuple(tableName, id));
```

Using a dedicated cache per table is usually faster and safes object allocations. However, if you have lots of tables, you end up with a lot of caches to configure and monitor. So, to make operations easier, a shared cache could be better.